# Magento 2 Observer not working on event 'checkout_onepage_controller_success_action'

Tags: magento, magento2

I've tried a lot of suggestions here but it seems like nothing works for me. I am trying to listen to event `'checkout_onepage_controller_success_action'`. I am trying to set the order status to 'complete' upon checkout (for now, I commented out that part).

As you may see below (inside the execute method), I am trying to print out the order object then exit. But when testing, nothing happens. No print out, no error message. Nothing...

I ran the following commands before testing:
`bin/magento setup:upgrade`, `bin/magento setup:di:compile`, `bin/magento cache:clean`

I also tried listening to event `sales_order_place_after`. I also got nothing...

**app/code/[company]/[module]/etc/frontend/events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_onepage_controller_success_action">
        <observer instance="[company]\[module]\Observer\CheckoutSuccessObserver" name="checkout_onepage_controller_success_action_observer"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

**app/code/[company]/[module]/Observer/CheckoutSuccessObserver.php**

```
<?php

namespace [company]\[module]\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer; 

/**
 * Class CheckoutSuccessObserver
 *
 * @package [company]\[module]\Observer
 */
class CheckoutSuccessObserver implements ObserverInterface
{

    /**
     * Execute observer
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer) 
    {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        print_r($order); exit;

        //$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        //$order_id = $order->getIncrementId();

        //$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($order_id);
        //$order->setData('state', "complete");
        //$order->setStatus("complete");      

        //$history = $order->addStatusHistoryComment('Order was set to complete by our automation tool.', false);
        //$history->setIsCustomerNotified(null);

        //$order->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your module is enable?

Comment: @Maeza Did you found the solution to this? I'm also facing similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your sample code looks ok.
Did you enable your custom module? Check it using `bin/magento module:status [company]_[module]`
Try also to clear the project's directories: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/howdoi/php/php_clear-dirs.html.